# Determine whether a polynomial is solvable by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, galois-theory

> Let $f(x) = x^{12}+2x^6-2x^3+2$ and let $K$ be it's splitting field. 
>   Is the Galois group of $K/Q$ solvable?

Since we're really only interested in the polynomial $x^4+2x^2-2x+2$, and we know that there exists a quartic formula.  It is enough to conclude that the polynomial is solvable by radicals and therefore the Galois group is solvable.  Is this solution correct?

The question also asks if this polynomial is irreducible.  This is easy to show via Eisenstein's criterion.  But is the irreducibility of the polynomial important in any way for showing it is solvable?

[Feb 2016](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Post_2012_papers/Alg_2012-.pdf)

Comment: Irreducibility is not needed since when you compute the roots in radicals you compute them all.

Answer (score 1):

The Galois group of $f(x)$ has order $3888=2^4\cdot 3^5$. For the computation one can use Magma online [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). This group is, by *Burnside's $p^rq^s$-Theorem* solvable, since the order has only two different prime divisors.
The polynomial $x^4+2x^2-2x+2$ has a solvable Galois group, see K. Conrad's article [Galois group of cubics and quartics](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf), namely one of the following solvable groups: $S_4,A_4,D_4,C_4,C_2\times C_2$. However, the Galois group of $x^{12}+2x^6-2x^3+2$ is quite different from these groups.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of "is the polynomial solvable by radicals?", in which case the galois group would also be solvable. And since every 4th degree polynomial is solvable by radicals, $y=x^3$ would imply $x$ is also a radical, so the original polynomial would also be solvable by radicals.  The galois groups dont necessarily have to be the same though

Comment: I see. Looks like you are right.